# how to put bars center of xaxis in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using echarts and I am trying to put bars center of each xaxis category

this is my chart :

[image: eecharts here]

I would like to each of bars match with xaxis label and center of category
(exactly like thrid bar only third bar is correct)

the red square shows extra space on xaxis

how can I do this? 
is there any option for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding **barGap: '-100'** on stacked bar series items

```
     option = {
    series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    stack: 'whatever',
    barGap: '-100'
    }]
    };
myChart.setOption(option);
```